# setPixels32() in unity creates blank textures

Tags: c#, textures, unity-game-engine, texture2d

I have an array of Texture2D's, which gets populated by the `webcamtexture` for a few seconds. That part works, all 50 or so frames show up in the inspector fine.

Now we modify those images by calling `.GetPixels32()` to get a `Color32[]` for each frame. as an example we can try to set each channel to the `Math.Max` of each pixel between the current frame and the frame prior (essentially a 'lighten' blend), and replace the texture in the array with the newly modified texture. (this code starts from the second frame, the problem is not from array out of bounds)

```
    Color32[] previousColors = previousFrame.GetPixels32();
    Color32[] currentColors = currentFrame.GetPixels32();
    Color32[] outColors = new Color32[colors.Length];
    int i = 0;
    while (i < currentColors .Length)
    {
        outColors[i].b = Math.Max(previousColors[i].b, currentColors[i].b);
        outColors[i].r = Math.Max(previousColors[i].r, currentColors[i].r);
        outColors[i].g = Math.Max(previousColors[i].g, currentColors[i].g);
    }
    bufferedPics[frameIndex].SetPixels32(outColors);
    bufferedPics[frameIndex].Apply();
```

Here's where the problem occurs: In the inspector, the frames in the array all now show up blank. But clicking the circle to the right of them, it shows the properly modified, lightened frame. Trying to use those frames elsewhere, they show up blank and transparent.

Comment: Can you show how you edit the pixels? Perhaps a sample operations (for instance setting a subregion to blue). Mind that since you construct a new array, all the pixels are set to transparent black.

Comment: Please give your question phrasing and formatting a bit more effort to make it easier for other users to understand your question and provide an answer.

Comment: @Xaser sorry about the formatting, this is the first post I've put up here. thank you for the fixes.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i've modified the code to show what's going on. essentially doing a Lighten blend on two consecutive frames. please let me know if anything stands out! I would think the transparent black is what is happening, but attaching a debugger to a breakpoint at the end shows the pixels have the expected values

Comment: @v8ntage: you never set the alpha channel to opaque.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem color32 is 0-255, doh! i was setting it to 1 as a float :( thank you!

Comment: @v8ntage: then I guess it was not fully black, perhaps here and there a very small amount of very dark gray :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Color32` has **four channels**: red, green, blue and **alpha**. By default, alpha is `0` (meaning transparent). You have to set alpha to **255** to let the image be opaque.

```
Color32[] previousColors = previousFrame.GetPixels32();
Color32[] currentColors = currentFrame.GetPixels32();
Color32[] outColors = new Color32[colors.Length];
int i = 0;
while (i < currentColors .Length)
{
    outColors[i].b = Math.Max(previousColors[i].b, currentColors[i].b);
    outColors[i].r = Math.Max(previousColors[i].r, currentColors[i].r);
    outColors[i].g = Math.Max(previousColors[i].g, currentColors[i].g);
    outColors[i].a = 255;  // set the alpha channel to opaque
}
bufferedPics[frameIndex].SetPixels32(outColors);
bufferedPics[frameIndex].Apply();
```